# How to change the values of certain rowns in a column of a MultiIndex Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, slice

I have a dataframe (df) with the following columns:

```
print(df.columns)
['A','B','C','D','E']
```

And let's assume all the columns have numbers as data.

Then I select some of the columns to become indexes

```
Index = ['A','B','C']
df.set_index(Index).sort_index()
```

and I use it this way for some analysis.At some point I need to change the rows of column 'E' when index 'C' has certain values, for instance something like :

```
df.loc[df[(slice(None,None),slice(None,None),slice(5,10))], 'E' ] = 6
```

Which, obviously, doesn't work. I have tried a bunch of different approaches: using tuples and slices for the index as shown in my line above, re-arranging the indexes so i can use a single slice (Moving 'C' to the first level), tried with .xs (cross section) etc and I cannot do it. (I have been looking into de documentation of .loc, .xs, etc) I don't find an example that does exactly this, nor I find conclusive answer that this is not possible. Right now I was able to do the following:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True) # returning it back into a normal DataFrame
df.loc[(DataFrame['C'] >= 5) & (df['C'] <= 10),'E'] = 6 # Modifying normally based on column data
df.set_index(Index).sort_index() # bring it back to a multiindex
```

But this doesn't seem right. It would seem to me that indexes should be able to be sliced somehow, I just can't find how. Perhaps I'm not searching the correct terms on Google. if anyone could give me a hand or point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.index.get_level_values('C')`--which returns an index array of the values--like below.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
df = df.set_index(['A','B','C']).sort_index()

df.loc[(df.index.get_level_values('C') <= 10) & (df.index.get_level_values('C') >= 5), 'E'] = 6

print(df)
```

Results:

```
       D  E                                              
A B C                                                    
0 0 6  3  6                                              
  2 0  6  1                                              
    7  2  6                                              
  3 6  5  6                                              
    9  1  6                                              
...   .. ..                                              
9 3 3  5  0                                              
    6  6  6                                              
  4 3  5  7                                              
    7  6  6                                              
  6 8  6  6
```

Note: The the parenthesis around both `.get_level_values()`s are required because otherwise the answer is ambiguous and will throw an error.